# iOS MPMusicPlayerController song changed notification does not have a song object with it

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am developing an app that listens to song changes of the MPMusicPlayerController.

For that, I am adding the following observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default
    .addObserver(self,
                 selector: #selector(systemSongDidChange(_:)),
                 name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
                 object: nil)
```

The problem is that, when the notification is fired, the `nowPlayingItem` that can be found at `(notification?.object as? MPMusicPlayerController)!.nowPlayingItem` is always `nil`.

Am I doing anything wrong or is there some special trick that must be done to retrieve the actual `nowPlayingItem`?

Here is a more complete code:

```
// ...
init() {
    let systemPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(systemSongDidChange(_:)),
                                           name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
                                           object: systemPlayer)

    player.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
}

private func systemSongDidChange(notification: Notification) {
    let currentSong = (notification.object as? MPMusicPlayerController)?.nowPlayingItem
    // `currentSong` is always `nil` =/
}
// ...
```

---

*The player I am using is the Apple's Music Player. I am not playing songs from the cloud.*

Comment: You are setting the object as nil, you need to set that as the item

Comment: Hello, @Tometoyou. Thank you for your reply. Could you give a more detailed explanation, please? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found out why the `nowPlayingItem` is always being `nil`.

It seems that the user **must** have allowed the app to access the "Media & Apple Music". If this access has not been granted, the app will not have permission to know what is currently playing on the system's player.

This authorization can be requested as follows:

```
// if not yet given or requested
MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { authorizationStatus in }
```

or

```
// if already requested and denied (will take user to the App Settings Page)
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the object within your notification, to be able to get the `nowPlayingItem`.

The code should look something like this:

```
private let playerController = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(systemSongDidChange(_:)),
    name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
    object: playerController
)
```

Then you should be able to access the `nowPlayingItem` like this in your systemSongDidChange function:

```
func systemSongDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let playerController = notification?.object as? MPMusicPlayerController else {
        return
    }
    let item = playerController.nowPlayingItem
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the further detailed explanation, @Tometoyou. I did just that, but the player I am using is `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer`. The `nowPlayingItem` being returned by the method is still `nil` =/

Comment: If the `nowPlayingItem` is nil, but the controller exists, then maybe you're not playing an item?

Comment: I am. I am always playing another song when interacting with the Apple's Music Player